# Built-In Add-Ins tab not displaying on the Ribbon of MS WORD 2010/2013

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

As the following image from my WORD 2013 shows the Add-Ins tab is missing from the `Ribbon` of the document even though "File-->Options-->Customize Ribbon Tabs" shows that the tab should display. Same is true for some other tabs shown in the list of `Main Tabs` on the left side of the image. **Question**: How can we display these missing tabs?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Add-ins tab does not have any commands on it. That is why it does not appear in the "Choose commands from" list. Unless you add some commands it will not show in your ribbon even though you have checked the box next to it in the right hand column.

Other tabs in the "Choose commands from" list, such as SmartArt Tools, are context tabs and appear only when in context. So SmartArt Tools only appears if you have a SmartArt object selected, Chart Tools only appears when a Chart is selected, Table Tools appears when a Table is selected, etc.

Context tabs appear in the right column only when you change the drop-down to either All Tabs or Tool Tabs.
[image]

Some of the tabs listed under Main Tabs are also context tabs, e.g. Blog Post and Insert (Blog Post) only appear when you create a blog post, Outlining appears only when a document is in Outline view.